# Why does SharePoint Online delete newest instead of oldest minor version when minor version limit is exceeded?

Tags: sharepoint-online

When saving a document in SharePoint Online, I get a message in Norwegian that can be translated to: "The limit for minor versions has been exceeded. From now on the newest minor version will be deleted.". Why delete the newest instead of the oldest? The minor version limit is 500 it seems. There is no way to change it for the document library. It takes a long time to make 500 versions of a document. That means the user is practically working without versioning if the newest version is overwritten.

Publishing a major version fixes the problem, but most users will just ignore the small yellow bar at the top with this all important message.

Answer (score 1):

The minor version limit is 511 actually.For doument library in sharepoint, allow up to 511 minor versions per major version.

Why it is 511? You could check the url of file's version, the format of the url would be this: `https://<yourisite>/_vti_history/<versionNumber>/<libraryName>/<fileName>`. The version number is calculated like this: `<major version>*512+<minor version>`

For example, version 1.1 using this `url:https://<yourisite>/_vti_history/513/<libraryName>/<fileName>`. version 2.0 using this url:`https://<yourisite>/_vti_history/1024/<libraryName>/<fileName>`

So, if you have more than 511 minor versions, there are no urls available for the minor version. That's why the newest minor version will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I'd still like to see minor version 1 deleted making version 1.x the new 1.(x-1) where x [2, 511] and have the new minor version occupy the now available slot 511. Shifting everything down like that was perhaps not done for performance reasons?

Comment: I undestand what you said. But it's impossible in sharepoint. Every minor verison have its's own url, you cannot make the x the new 1. If you have more than 511 ninor vesion, the only way is to publish a moajor vesion.

Comment: IMHO Microsoft should change the behaviour for minor version overflow in SharePoint Online :) They should keep newest versions, not oldest.